# JMS Topic queue size always 0

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, geronimo

If i post a bunch of messages to a topic where the subscriber is very slow. The "Queue Size" in geronimos " JMS Resources" tab stays 0. If I use a JMS Queue instead of the topic, I can see the size growing. In both scenarios all messages are delivered.

Why does the "Queue Size" of the topic shows always 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A topic represents the publish-subscribe model, and messages will disappear when no subscriber is listening. Therefor a query on the topic size is always zero.

Topics can have multiple subscribers, so a message can be read on multiple clients "listening" on that topic.

Queues on the other hand will keep the messages until a client asks for the next message. Here you can query for the size of the currently held amount of messages. A message can be picked up only by one client.

See also the [Basic JMS API concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdx.html) by Oracle.

Described for ideal circumstances, durable topics as well as temporary queues are not considered here.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear about my question, but what i really wanted to know is: in a scenario where topics are involved and listener are available, messages don't disappear if the consumer/listener takes longer to to process the message, than it takes thw producer to generate one. The topic message get "queued" i wanted to know where i can look up how many messages are queued for a specific consumer via JMS.

Comment: Hm, I don't know Geronimo well, but it uses ActiveMQ. Did you checked the JMX resource, possibly it is the "inflight count"? http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-find-the-size-of-a-queue.html and http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html